# CSS: :focus-within not working on dynamic JavaScript-generated content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm displaying search suggestions as anchors inside the dropdown of a searchbar. If there's focus-within the .searchbar element, the dropdown is visible. This works when I type the dropdown suggestions by hand but as soon as I use Javascript to generate them, the focus-within stops working.

```js
searchinput.oninput = generateSuggestions;

function generateSuggestions() {
  searchbar_dropdown.innerHTML = '';
  for (suggestion of show_suggestions) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.src = 'explore.php?search=' + suggestion['suggestion'];
    a.innerText = suggestion['suggestion'];
    searchbar_dropdown.appendChild(a);
  }

  // I tried these two but it isn't working
  window.requestAnimationFrame();
  searchbar_dropdown.offsetHeight;
}
```

```css
.searchbar:focus-within .suggestions {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 43px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbar float float-up delay05">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="dropdown suggestions"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code example seems incomplete. Without a complete example of your code we cannot help you debug your code.

Comment: Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly the HTML you are creating and compared it to the version you create by hand?

Comment: I ran a simple test using your code and one 'suggestion' - the focus worked fine so there may be something that you haven't shown us that is causing the problem. Have you checked the dev tools console for errors?

Comment: Thank you A Haworth for trying to help with my problem! I found the mistake (which is btw. clearly visible in my question for anyone who said it's incomplete): I was accidentally setting the src Attribute and not the href attribute of the <a> elements. Turns our anchors without href are not focusable, thats why focus-within isn't working either.